# Transclude directive fails to modify content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined a transclude directive as beliw in AngularJs 1.3 - but it does not seem to have any effect on the rendering.
A log statement in the link phase shows that the directive is invoked though.

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="directivesApp">
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="directiveCtrl">
    <label>Geography</label><input type="text" ng-model="geography"/>
    <br>
    <div transclude-demo>
    <button ng-click='showGeography()'>Show Geography</button>
    <a href="#">and a link</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('directivesApp', [])
.controller('directiveCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.showGeography=function(){alert('I am here');}
})
.directive('transcludeDemo',function(){
    return{
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude> This is my directive content</div>',
        link:function ($scope, element, attrs) { console.log('invoked in scope');}
    }
});
```

I would have expected the transclude directive to replace/modify the contents of the div,with the contents of its template.
However,I find that the div is rendered as-is.

Is this how a transclude directive is expected to work?

Comment: You should see the button and a link render instead of the text `"This is my directive content"`. `ng-transclude` replaces the content of its element with the transcluded content

Comment: For a better test, replace your directive template by `<div><div ng-transclude></div><div>This is my directive content</div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transclude is used to preserve the content that's already there, so if you just want to replace the content all you really need is the template. You're not seeing much in your example because your containing divs are essentially the same.

**Replace content:**

```
.directive('transcludeDemo',function(){
    return{
        template: '<div>This is my directive content</div>',
        link:function ($scope, element, attrs) { console.log('invoked in scope');}
    }
});
```

If you'd like to combine the new/old content in some way, add something in your template outside of the `ng-transclude` and it will render in combination.

**Combine with transclude:**

```
.directive('transcludeDemo',function(){
    return{
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div>' +
                     '<p>This text will stay in tact</p>' +
                     '<div ng-transclude>This text will be replaced</div>' +
                  '</div>',
        link:function ($scope, element, attrs) { console.log('invoked in scope');}
    }
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, this second example should give you a better understanding of what's actually happening.